# How to storage sensors value in JSON string

Tags: c, json, arduino

i'm doing with JSON string, i want to storage my sensor data to JSON string then i will send it to Node red or firebase (which i heard is it need JSON format, not sure about that). My actually project is receive lots of sensors value like

["ID": 01, "temp": value_temp_1, "humid": value_humid_1] , ["ID": 02, "temp": value_temp_2, "humid": value_humid_2],...

```
#include <DHT.h>
#include <DHT_U.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#define DHTPIN 2
#define DHTTYPE DHT11
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
int humidity, temperature;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Begin");
  dht.begin();
}
void loop() 
{
  delay(2000);
  humidity = dht.readHumidity();
  temperature = dht.readTemperature();
  StaticJsonDocument<50> doc;
  JsonObject object = doc.to<JsonObject>();  
  object["ID"] = "Node01";
  object["humidity"] = humidity;
  object["temperature"] = temperature;
  serializeJson(doc, Serial);
  Serial.println("");
}
```

my question is do i have to use those code in loop()? everytime it will create a Json<50> so it will be full later or it only create 1 time? i have little confuse about that or could anyone give me some advices to optimize my code.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create your `object` each time. Just define it as a global variable and change its values on your loop. Something like this:

```
#include <DHT.h>
#include <DHT_U.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#define DHTPIN 2
#define DHTTYPE DHT11

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
int humidity, temperature;

StaticJsonDocument<50> doc;
JsonObject object;

void setup()
{
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Begin");
  dht.begin();
  object = doc.to<JsonObject>();
}

void loop()
{
  humidity = dht.readHumidity();
  temperature = dht.readTemperature();
  object["ID"] = "Node01";
  object["humidity"] = humidity;
  object["temperature"] = temperature;
  serializeJson(doc, Serial);
  Serial.println("");
  delay(2000);
}
```

Comment: thank you, it work now. could you help me the code. i want to format my json like this 
{"Payload":{
  "1" : {
    "temp":"value",
    "humid":"value",
  },
  "2": { //this is id
    "temp":"value",
    "rssi":"value",
  }
}}
`int id = header.from_node; //return 1, 2 ,3,...`
i search nest object also

Comment: Please create a new question, add explain what are you trying to do.